# how to use panda list in a spark sql query

Tags: pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a list of unique encounter_id in a panda list converting from spark data frame.

```
# Convert spark sql dataframe into pandas
df_hos105_vanco_info= hos105_vanco_info.toPandas()

# Create a unique encounter pd list for encounter_id
hos105_vanco_info_encounter_list=df_hos105_vanco_info['encounter_id'].drop_duplicates().values.tolist()
```

This list contains 800 unique encounter IDs, how can I use this list to create a query condition in spark sql?

I tried this but is seems the logic is incorrect.

```
hos105_vanco_lab_detail=spark.sql("select *\
from hf_f_encounter e\
join hf_f_lab_procedure l\
on e.encounter_id=l.encounter_id\
where e.encounter_id in hos105_vanco_info_encounter_list")

hos105_vanco_lab_detail.count()
```

Comment: You should be able to just add an additional inner join to select the records that are in ```df_hos105_vanco_info```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is, if you are working with Spark objects, you stick with spark objects, if you work with pandas objects, you stick with pandas objects. If you want to mix them together, then you should explicitly convert them from one "world" to the other "world".

So in this case, if you want to work with `spark.sql`, the easiest way is to convert the `encounter_list` to another spark object. Minimal example is here:

```py
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1,2,3],
    'b': [4,5,6]
})

# pretend this is your list of ids you are filtering off.
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1]
})

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("example").getOrCreate()

spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
spark_df2 = spark.createDataFrame(df2)

spark_df.registerTempTable("spark_df")
spark_df2.registerTempTable("spark_df2")

result = spark.sql("""select * from spark_df where a in (select a from spark_df2)""")
```